# Sending JSON through amqp-publish from bash

Tags: json, bash, amqp

I have a shell script that sends text messages through amqp-publish to a Java Spring RabbitMQ server.

```
amqp-publish -u amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/%2f -r "queue.udrive.ustorage" -e "directExchangeUdrive" -b "$msg"
```

So I want to send a JSON message and I did like this but I got errors...

```
amqp-publish -u amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/%2f -r "queue.udrive.ustorage" -e "directExchangeUdrive" -p -C application/json "$msg"
Usage: amqp-publish [-?] [-u|--url=amqp://...] [-s|--server=hostname] [--port=port] [--vhost=vhost] [--username=username]
        [--password=password] [--ssl] [--cacert=cacert.pem] [--key=key.pem] [--cert=cert.pem] [-e|--exchange=exchange]
        [-r|--routing-key=routing key] [-p|--persistent] [-C|--content-type=content type] [-t|--reply-to=reply to]
        [-l|--line-buffered] [-E|--content-encoding=content encoding] [-b|--body=body] [-?|--help] [--usage] [OPTIONS]...
```

Answer (score 1):

add `-b` parameter before `"$msg"`

`amqp-publish -u amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/%2f -r "queue.udrive.ustorage" -e "directExchangeUdrive" -p -C application/json` **-b** `"$msg"`